# Imaginary part of $f(z)$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, residue-calculus

I have to find the analytic function $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ knowing that $$v(x,y)=\Phi(x)\cdot\Psi(y)$$

The Laplacian of $v$, which must be $0$, is $$\Delta v= \frac{\partial^2v}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2v}{\partial y^2}=\Phi''(x)\cdot\Psi(y)+\Phi(x)\cdot\Psi''(y)=0$$

Is it possible to solve this equation? Is it some sort of Exact Differential Equation?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: If $\Phi, \Psi$ are non-zero, $\Phi''(x)/\Phi(x) = -\Psi''(y)/\Psi(y)$. The left-hand side does not depend on $y$, and the right-hand side does not depend on $x$. What does this tell you?

Comment: It means that $\frac{\Phi''(x)}{\Phi(x)}=-\frac{\Psi''(y)}{\Psi(y)}=C$, where $C$ is a real constant. Now I have to solve two differential equations $\Phi''-C\Phi=0$ and $\Psi''+C\Psi=0$?

Comment: Yes, that'll do it! Note that $C = 0$ and $C > 0$ and $C < 0$ are all possible. (You might find it nicer to write some general solutions in terms of $\exp(\alpha x + \beta)$ for various $\alpha,\beta$.)